# Avoiding unsafe casting with generics

Tags: java, generics

Lets say I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal>{
...
}
```

I'd like all child classes to have a common method that checks the training status of a trainer on a given animal. So I have in my Trainer definition:

```
public abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal>{
   public double getStatus(Animal a){
   ...
   }
}
```

so that anyone can query a trainer regardless of it's specific type. However, to make the individual trainers responsible for reporting their own status, I requiring a that the individual trainers implement an `internalGetStatus` method which I'd then like my `getStatus` method to call. So what I'm currently doing is:

```
public abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal>{
   protected abstract internalGetStatus(T theAnimal);
   public double getStatus(Animal a){
     return internalGetStatus((T) a);
   }
}
```

The problem is, of course, `return internalGetStatus((T) a);` involves an unchecked type cast which throws up a warning I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way to do that?

Because of some design limitations beyond my control, when the status is being queried for a particular animal, it is provided as an object of the parent class Animal and not the specific animal type that the trainer is created for.

Comment: Why does getStatus take *Animal* ? Why not accept *T* ? There is nothing wrong in casting it to *T* as long as the base of T has been defined.

Comment: @anishthecoder any reason why you can't change your 'public double getStatus(Animal a)' method to 'public double getStatus(T a)' ?

Comment: @DevBlanked @HarshaR, because of some design limitations beyond my control, my getStatus methods can only be supplied `Animal` and not `T`....

Comment: @anishthecoder may be you could use 'getActualTypeArguments()' method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29 and then use 'isInstance' method on class to determine if 'a' is actully of type 'T'

Comment: Is it me or that can't work? If you have a Trainer<Lion> and you query it with a Leopard parameter for the status: it won't work at all.

Comment: @zenbeni Agree. But assuming I am somewhat guaranteed that only `Lions` will be given to the `Trainer<Lion>`? Meaning, the external framework (out of my control) that uses the `LionTrainer`, will only use it with `Lions`, but can't give me the Lion as a `Lion`, only as an `Animal`....

Comment: Well, if it gives you explicitely an Animal value, that can't work either as Animal cast to Lion will return null if the instance is not actually a Lion. If it is indeed a Lion, you can make the method generic and add the cast from outside the class: it will be placed where it is most understandable: not hiding it in case someone would break this silent API.

Comment: @zenbeni, a non-lion Animal cast to Lion will not return anything. It will throw an exception.

Comment: @anishthecoder, what is the correct behavior of `getStatus` when called with an `Animal` that is not a `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the classes are used. However, you didn't say much about that. Let's start with the following code:

```
abstract class Animal { }

final class Lion extends Animal { }

abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal> {
    public abstract double getStatus(T animal);
}

final class LionTrainer extends Trainer<Lion> {
    public double getStatus(Lion lion) {
        return 4.2;
    }
}
```

You mentioned that the call-side of the `getStatus` method doesn't know the animal type. That means he isn't using `Trainer<Lion>`, but either the *raw type*, `Trainer<Animal>` or a *wildcard type*. Let's go through these three cases.

**Raw Type:** The type parameter doesn't matter for raw types. You can invoke the method `getStatus` with `Animal`. This works as long as the sub-types of `Trainer` and `Animal` match. Otherwise, you will see a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

```
void raw(Trainer trainer, Animal animal) {
    trainer.getStatus(animal);
}
```

**`Trainer<Animal>:`** Obviously, you can invoke the method `getStatus` of an `Trainer<Animal>` with an `Animal`. It similar to the above case. The static type system doesn't ware, and at runtime you will see an exception, if the types don't match.

```
void base(Trainer<Animal> trainer, Animal animal) {
    trainer.getStatus(animal);
}
```

Note that you can pass a `LionTrainer` to this method (with cast), because at runtime there is no difference between `Trainer<Animal>` and `Trainer<Lion>`.

**Wildcard Type:** Well, that does not work on the caller-side - without casting the `Trainer<?>` to something else. The `?` stands for an unknown sub-type of `Animal` (including the base class itself).

```
void wildcard(Trainer<?> trainer, Animal animal) {
    trainer.getStatus(animal); // ERROR
}
```

The result is, if the framework uses either the *raw type* or the *base type*, then there shouldn't be a problem. Otherwise it's simpler to add the cast to your code, suppress the warning with an annotation, and document why you have decided to go that way.